# Is there a measurable space that cannot be covered by countable union of disjoint finite sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Take some set $X$ with a non-counting measure $\mu$ attached to it. Is it possible that $X=\cup_{\alpha\in A}S_\alpha$ an uncountable disjoint union where $\mu(S_\alpha)=c$ some fixed finite number for all $\alpha$.

Certainly $\mathbb R=\cup_{r\in\mathbb R}\{r\}$ and $\mu(r)=1$ for each $r$ if we take counting measure, so I wish to exclude that possibility.

As far as I know, this is not possible with $\mathbb R$ and Lebesgue measure. I.e. we cannot break apart $\mathbb R$ into an uncountable disjoint union of sets of positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking whether or not there are non $\sigma-$finite measure spaces, is it not? Also if you found the given answer below useful you should accept it.

Comment: @William, It may be. I certainly was looking for a measure space that isn't $\sigma$-finite but is coverable by an uncountable collection of finite measure sets. I'll probably accept the answer given but want to think about it. I didn't anticipate a mix of counting and Lebesgue measures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $X=\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ with $\mu(A)=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{R}} \lambda(A_r)$, where $A_r=\{s\in[0,1]:(r,s)\in A\}$ and $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.  Then $X$ is the disjoint union of the sets $S_r=\{r\}\times[0,1]$ for each $r\in\mathbb{R}$, each of which has measure $1$.

More generally, given any family of measure spaces, you can take their disjoint union with the obvious induced measure.  If you had an uncountable family of measure spaces, each of total measure $c$, then the disjoint union is a disjoint union of subsets of measure $c$.

Comment: That was slick... feel like I should have seen that coming! Thanks!

Comment: It seems like your measure is the product of Lebesgue on $[0,1]$ and counting on $\mathbb R$. If you have an explicit example which doesn't use counting measure at all, I'd appreciate it, but no worries either way.

Comment: Just replace $\{r\}\times[0,1]$ with your favorite probability space $(X_r,\lambda_r)$ for each $r$ and define $\mu(A)=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{R}} \lambda_r(A_r)$ similarly on $X=\bigsqcup X_r$.  (This is what I was referring to in the second paragraph.)